# Array structure

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to make a little custom vector...

element class, should point to the adress of the next class but with this code

```
class foo {
private:
    int attr;
public:
    foo(){attr = 10;}
    int get_attr(){return attr;}
    void set_attr(int a){attr =a;}
};

class element_foo {
private:
    foo data;
    element_foo *ptr_next;
public:
    element_foo(){ptr_next = NULL;}
    element_foo(int dat){data.set_attr(dat); ptr_next = NULL;}
    element_foo(int dat, element_foo next){
        data.set_attr(dat);
        ptr_next = &next;
    }
    foo get_data(){return data;}

    element_foo get_next(){return *ptr_next;}

    void print_array(){
        if (ptr_next == NULL) {
            std::cout<< data.get_attr()<<std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout<< data.get_attr()<<std::endl;
            this->get_next().print_array();
        }

    }
};



int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    // insert code here...  
    element_foo a1(10);
    element_foo a2(15,a1);
    element_foo a3(20,a2);

    a3.print_array();

    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

when I print a3, it get to segmentation fault... why? where is my mistake?

Comment: Semantic Note: What you are implementing is more of a list rather than a vector.  Typically, a vector is understood to mean a dynamic collection of elements stored contiguously in memory.  Of course, you can make it mean whatever you want, but it might confuse others down the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in this constructor:

```
element_foo(int dat, element_foo next){
    data.set_attr(dat);
    ptr_next = &next;
}
```

You are taking the address of a local. `ptr_next = &next;` Once the function ends, the address is invalid.

What you need to do is to pass `next` in as a pointer:

```
element_foo(int dat, element_foo *next){
    data.set_attr(dat);
    ptr_next = next;
}
```

And change your main to this:

```
element_foo a1(10);
element_foo a2(15,&a1);
element_foo a3(20,&a2);
```

EDIT:

Alternatively, you can just pass it by reference:

```
element_foo(int dat, element_foo &next){
    data.set_attr(dat);
    ptr_next = &next;
}
```

Comment: Pointer? Why not a reference?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: It didn't cross my mind when I answered. But yes, that would work too.

Comment: I've putted a reference, and it works perfectly, thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are storing a pointer to a temporary object.

'`next`' is just a ***copy*** of `a1`/`a2` you passed in because of copy-by-value. You should use copy-by-reference so that `&next` refers exactly to the address of `a1`/`a2`, not a copy of them.

```
                     v-------- should use "const element_foo &"
element_foo(int dat, element_foo next){
        data.set_attr(dat);
        ptr_next = &next;
    }

// a2->ptr_next is dangling
element_foo a2(15,a1);
```

When the above line is executed, `a2->ptr_next` doesn't not point to `a1`,
but a temporary local object which has already been destructed.
Thus `a2->ptr_next` is dangling. Any later access via this pointer has undefined behavior.